# Slicing a list into a list of sub-lists

Tags: list, python

What is the simplest and reasonably efficient way to slice a list into a list of the sliced sub-list sections for arbitrary length sub lists?

For example, if our source list is:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ... ]
```

And our sub list length is 3 then we seek:

```
output = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], ... ]
```

Likewise if our sub list length is 4 then we seek:

```
output = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], ... ]
```

Comment: You may be interested in the discussion of this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095637)

Comment: You could use numpy's array_split function e.g., `np.array_split(np.array(data), 20)` to split into 20 nearly equal size chunks. To make sure chunks are exactly equal in size use `np.split`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
[input[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(input), n)]        # Use xrange in py2k
```

where `n` is the length of a chunk.

Since you don't define what might happen to the final element of the new list when the number of elements in `input` is not divisible by `n`, I assumed that it's of no importance: with this you'll get last element equal 2 if `n` equal 7, for example.

Answer (score 17):

The documentation of the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module contains the following [recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
import itertools

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

This function returns an iterator of tuples of the desired length:

```
>>> list(grouper(2, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, None)]
```

Comment: while this is working with any iterable, it doesn't seem to be as efficient (at least in my tests) as my code when applied to the given task.

Comment: @SilentGhost, Premature optimization?

Answer (score 10):

A really pythonic variant (python 3):

```
list(zip(*(iter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),)*3))
```

A list iterator is created and turned into a tuple with 3x the same iterator, then unpacked to zip and casted to list again. One value is pulled from each iterator by zip, but as there is just a single iterator object, the internal counter is increased globally for all three.

Comment: This solution is brilliant, but if I had to consider the zen of python I'd say it's not very "pythonic" :P

Comment: True, it's a non-pythonic pythonic solution ;-)

Comment: Does NOT work if mod of len of list is not 0!

Comment: does not work !

Answer (score 1):

I like SilentGhost's solution.

My solution uses functional programming in python:

```
group = lambda t, n: zip(*[t[i::n] for i in range(n)])
group([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
```

gives:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

This assumes that the input list size is divisible by the group size. If not, unpaired elements will not be included.

Comment: your second example is limited to python-2.x. in py3k `map` cannot take `None` as a first argument.

Comment: @SilentGhost: you are right, I'm removing it though.