# how to parse a list or string into chunks of fixed length

Tags: python

I'm really stuck on a basic question. I am trying to take a list of one item and divide it into a list of many items each with a charater length of 10. For example give a list with one item, `['111111111122222222223333333333']`, the output would produce:

```
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
```

I feel like this is super simple, but I'm stumped. I tried to create a function like this:

```
def parser(nub):    
    while len(nub) > 10:  
        for subnub in nub:  
            subnub = nub[::10]
            return(subnub)  
    else:  
        print('Done')
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. Any advice? Would using a string be easier than a list?

Comment: can you rephrase this please: `I am trying to iterate through a list of n length into sublists of 10 characters.` i don't get it.

Comment: @mouad edited for clarity, i hope that helped.

Comment: Edit  title for spelling. Also, your string doesn't need to be inside of a list. Also, did I not already answer your question? (see below)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A related question has been asked:
[Slicing a list into a list of sub-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231663/slicing-a-list-into-a-list-of-sub-lists)

For example, if your source list is:

```
the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ... ]
```

you can split it like:

```
split_list = [the_list[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(the_list), n)]
```

assuming n is your sub-list length and the result would be:

```
[[1, 2, 3, ..., n], [n+1, n+2, n+3, ..., 2n], ...]
```

Then you can iterate through it like:

```
for sub_list in split_list:
    # Do something to the sub_list
```

The same thing goes for strings.

Here's a practical example:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> listo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> split_list = [listo[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(listo), n)]
>>> split_list
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]

>>> listo = '123456789'
>>> split_list = [listo[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(listo), n)]
>>> split_list
['12', '34', '56', '78', '9']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
value = '111111111122222222223333333333'
n = 10
(value[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(value), n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has been posted after 4 years, but here is a another way to do this use [`textwrap` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html). From the document:

> `textwrap.wrap(text[, width[, ...]])`
>
> Wraps the single paragraph in text (a string) so every line is at most width characters long. Returns a list of output lines, without final newlines.
>
> Optional keyword arguments correspond to the instance attributes of TextWrapper, documented below. width defaults to 70.

So we can do it like this：

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> myList = ['111111111122222222223333333333']

>>> [i for text in myList for i in textwrap.wrap(text, 10)]
['1111111111', '2222222222', '3333333333']

>>> for i in [i for text in myList for i in textwrap.wrap(text, 10)]:
...     print i
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other ways to do it recursively:

**Option 1: Recursive function**

```
>>> def chunks(x, n=10):
...      if len(x) <= n:
...          return [x]
...      else:
...          return [x[:n]] + chunks(x.replace(x[:n], ''))
...
>>> seq = ['111111111122222222223333333333']
>>> print chunks(seq[0])
['1111111111', '2222222222', '3333333333']
```

**Option 2: Recursive *lambda***

```
>>> n = 10
>>> chunks = lambda x: [x] if len(x) <= n else [x[:n]] + chunks(x.replace(x[:n], ''))
>>> print chunks(seq[0])
['1111111111', '2222222222', '3333333333']
```