# how to Merge two strings based on some conditions

Tags: python

this are two strings

```
a=  PVT corner         |    TYP_25    |    SLOW_125 |    SLOW_0_   |    SLOW_40 |    FAST_125 

b= Description         |  RD   |  WR | A   |  RD     |  WR     |  RD     |  WR     |  RD     |  WR     |  RD     |  WR
```

I need to check the length of each item in "a" and compare with "b". And if any "|" found in between item in "b" then it has to be concatenated with a's item, like this,
"RD" ,"WR" and "A" should be concatenated with TYP_25 of a.
how to Merge two strings based on this condition?

Comment: Have you tried anything, yet?

Comment: i tried to split and concatenate, but didnt work..

Comment: It would be better if you posted your code.

Is the number of sub-items in string b under a given item in string a always the same, that is 3 for the first and 2 for the others? I need more examples of possible string A's. Also, is the field length  in strings a and b identical?

Comment: I would do a search for | in a, keep a track of each range (e.g. first result to 2nd result, 2nd + 1 to 3rd and so on) and do a sub string for that same range in b then split the substring in b on '|' and concatenate all the results into the substring from the range of A and then do whatever you want with the result. EDIT: if this is fixed width then it becomes much simpler. create a and b sublists for each column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372228/how-to-parse-a-list-or-string-into-chucks-of-fixed-length and then split,map trim, join each of b and add to corresponding a element

Comment: What does "concatenate" mean?

Comment: This looks like a fixed-width format; are all the columns the same width perhaps?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `zip` works, regardless of whether the widths are equal.

```
a = "  PVT corner         |    TYP_25    |    SLOW_125    SLOW_0_   |    SLOW_M40|    FAST_12 "
b = " Description         |  RD   |  WR | A   |  RD     |  WR     |  RD     |  WR     |  RD     |  WR     |  RD     |  WR     "
head = 0
res = []
for i,(s,t) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
    if (s,t) == ("|","|"):
        res.append([a[head:i].strip()]+[m.strip() for m in b[head:i].split("|")])
        head = i + 1
res.append([a[head:].strip()]+[m.strip() for m in b[head:].split("|")])

for r in res:
    print r
```

The output is

```
['PVT corner', 'Description']
['TYP_25', 'RD', 'WR', 'A']
['SLOW_125', 'RD', 'WR']
['SLOW_0', 'RD', 'WR']
['SLOW_40', 'RD', 'WR']
['FAST_125', 'RD', 'WR']
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution, however. This loops over the inputs character by character instead of using more efficient slicing methods. Use this only if your column widths are variable, not fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You have a `|` character every 20 positions; split your strings into sections of 20 characters, and pair up the results:

```
def by_width(line, width=20, stripchars='|'):
    i = 0
    while i < len(line):
        yield line[i:i+width].strip(stripchars)
        i += width
```

Zip the results together gives:

```
>>> for column_a, column_b in zip(by_width(a), by_width(b)):
...     print [column_a.strip()] + [v.strip() for v in column_b.split('|')]
... 
['PVT corner', 'Description']
['TYP_25_0P85', 'RD', 'WR', 'A']
['SLOW_125_0P765', 'RD', 'WR']
['SLOW_0_0P765', 'RD', 'WR']
['SLOW_M40_0P765', 'RD', 'WR']
['FAST_125_0P935', 'RD', 'WR']
```

From there on out you can do what you want with the columns; in the above sample I merely put them together into lists of whitespace-stripped strings.

Comment: I want like this, TYP_25_0P85 RD, TYP_25_0P85 WR,  TYP_25_0P85 A

Comment: @ApoorvaShankar: then add an additional loop inside the first, looping over `column_b.split('|')` and combining that with `column_a`.

Answer (score 1):

if the format is confirmed, I think this would be ok:

```
tmp_flag1 = "#"
tmp_flag2 = "|"
tmp_str1 = a.replace(tmp_flag1, "")
tmp_str2 = b.replace(tmp_flag1, "")

tmp_str3 = ""
tmp_pos_head = 0
tmp_pos_tail = 0
tmp_is_equal = False

tmp_ret = tmp_str1.find(tmp_flag2)
while tmp_ret != -1:
        tmp_pos_tail = tmp_ret
        if tmp_str2[tmp_ret] == tmp_flag2:
                tmp_buf1 = tmp_str1[tmp_pos_head:tmp_pos_tail].replace(tmp_flag2, "")
                tmp_buf2 = tmp_str2[tmp_pos_head:tmp_pos_tail].replace(tmp_flag2, "")
                tmp_str3 += tmp_buf1 + ":" + tmp_buf2 + "\n"
                tmp_pos_head = tmp_ret + 1
                tmp_is_equal = True

         tmp_ret = tmp_str1.find(tmp_flag2, tmp_ret + 1)

if tmp_is_equal == True:
        tmp_buf1 = tmp_str1[tmp_pos_tail:].replace(tmp_flag2, "")
        tmp_buf2 = tmp_str2[tmp_pos_tail:].replace(tmp_flag2, "")
else:
        tmp_buf1 = tmp_str1[tmp_pos_head:].replace(tmp_flag2, "")
        tmp_buf2 = tmp_str2[tmp_pos_head:].replace(tmp_flag2, "")
tmp_str3 += tmp_buf1 + ":" + tmp_buf2

print tmp_str3
```