# Manipulating a string to create even chunks of three

Tags: python, string, input

I am new to Python, and this is probably a very simple question, but I am having trouble figuring it out. I have some raw input that I need to convert. The input is a body of text such as `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO'` but in order for me to continue, I need to convert this into a string such as `'ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO'`.

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231663/slicing-a-list-into-a-list-of-sub-lists

Comment: `I` is there O_o. I mean, input != output at all (and the input's ordering is quite scrambled anyways)

Comment: Although `f` is small in the output and there is a `F` between `K` and `L`.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO'
>>> ' '.join([s[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(s), 3)])
'ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO'
```