# Splitting a Python list into a list of overlapping chunks

Tags: python

This question is similar to *[Slicing a list into a list of sub-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231663/slicing-a-list-into-a-list-of-sub-lists)*, but in my case I want to include the last element of each previous sub-list as the first element in the next sub-list. And I have to take into account that the last sub-list always has to have at least two elements.

For example:

```
list_ = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
```

The result for a size 3 sub-list:

```
resultant_list = [['a','b','c'],['c','d','e'],['e','f','g'],['g','h']]
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The list comprehension in the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2231685/674039) is easily adapted to support overlapping chunks by simply shortening the "step" parameter passed to the range:

```
>>> list_ = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> n = 3  # group size
>>> m = 1  # overlap size
>>> [list_[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(list_), n-m)]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['g', 'h']]
```

Other visitors to this question mightn't have the luxury of working with an input *list* (slicable, known length, finite).  Here is a generator-based solution that can work with arbitrary iterables:

```
from collections import deque

def chunks(iterable, chunk_size=3, overlap=0):
    # we'll use a deque to hold the values because it automatically
    # discards any extraneous elements if it grows too large
    if chunk_size < 1:
        raise Exception("chunk size too small")
    if overlap >= chunk_size:
        raise Exception("overlap too large")
    queue = deque(maxlen=chunk_size)
    it = iter(iterable)
    i = 0
    try:
        # start by filling the queue with the first group
        for i in range(chunk_size):
            queue.append(next(it))
        while True:
            yield tuple(queue)
            # after yielding a chunk, get enough elements for the next chunk
            for i in range(chunk_size - overlap):
                queue.append(next(it))
    except StopIteration:
        # if the iterator is exhausted, yield any remaining elements
        i += overlap
        if i > 0:
            yield tuple(queue)[-i:]
```

*Note:* I've since released this implementation in [`wimpy.util.chunks`](https://github.com/wimglenn/wimpy/blob/v0.6/wimpy/util.py#L84-L107).  If you don't mind adding the dependency, you can `pip install wimpy` and use `from wimpy import chunks` rather than copy-pasting the code.

Comment: This method can result in unnecessary "stubs" being left over, for example if you run your first example on `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']`, it produces 
`[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['g']]`.

To avoid such unnecessary chunks that contain only elements already captured in previous chunks, subtract the overlap size `m` from the list length when calculating the range, i.e. `[list_[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(list_)-m, n-m)]`

Answer (score 14):

[`more_itertools.windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.windowed) is a sliding window tool for overlapping iterables.

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

**Code**

```
windows = list(mit.windowed(iterable, n=3, step=2))
windows
# [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'd', 'e'), ('e', 'f', 'g'), ('g', 'h', None)]
```

If required, you can drop the `None` fillvalue by filtering the windows:

```
[list(filter(None, w)) for w in windows]
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['g', 'h']]
```

Comment: I really like the fact that it fills the groups with `None`, is there any way to do it with the standard library?

Comment: @MattM. Sure.  Here is an alternative using itertools: `list(itertools.islice(itertools.zip_longest(s, s[1:], s[2:]), None, None, 2))`, where `s = "abcdefgh"`.  Notice, `None` is also controlled by a `fillvalue` parameter in `zip_longest`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = zip (l[:-1], l[1:])
for i in x:
    print (i)

(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
(5, 6)
```

Zip accepts any number of iterables, there is also `zip_longest`

Comment: How does this answer the question? O.P. wants chunks of size 3, with step 2.