# All possible chunks of list in python

Tags: python, list

Given a list eg. [2,3,4,10,20,30,102] 
I need all possible chunks/sublists of length 3 as follows,

```
[[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 10], [4, 10, 20], [10, 20, 30], [20, 30, 102]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find all the subsets of a set, with exactly n elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374626/how-can-i-find-all-the-subsets-of-a-set-with-exactly-n-elements)

Comment: @CaptainTrunky This is definitely not a duplicate of the linked question.  This is a about consecutive subsequences rather than subsets.

Comment: I've retracted the flag from this question, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a python list into a list of overlapping chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586897/splitting-a-python-list-into-a-list-of-overlapping-chunks)

Comment: @Georgy it is not though it is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
l= [2,3,4,10,20,30,102] 
res=[l[i:i+3] for i in range(len(l)-2)]
print(res)
```

This prints

```
[[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 10], [4, 10, 20], [10, 20, 30], [20, 30, 102]]
```

Comment: As your code is shorter and optimized, I accept your answer ty.

Answer (score 1):

this function will do the work and more

```
def chunks(sequence, length):
    sub_sequences = [sequence[offset:] 
                     for offset in range(length)]
    return zip(*sub_sequences)
```

for your example

```
list(chunks([2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30, 102], length=3))
```

gives desired output

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)  and a [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) operation will do you a favor.

Sample output

```
>>> a = [2,3,4,10,20,30,102]

>>> max_len = 3
>>> [ a[i-max_len: i] for i in xrange(max_len, len(a))]
[[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 10], [4, 10, 20], [10, 20, 30]]

>>> max_len = 5
>>> [ a[i-max_len: i] for i in xrange(max_len, len(a))]
[[2, 3, 4, 10, 20], [3, 4, 10, 20, 30]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [2,3,4,10,20,30,102]
arr2 = arr
arr3 =[]
while (len(arr2) >= 3):
   arr4=arr2[:3]
   arr2 = arr2[1:]
   arr3.append(arr4)
print("Original List \n")
print(arr)
print("\n")
print("List with all the chunks \n")
print(arr3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use slicing:

```
>>> s = [2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30, 102]
>>> [s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s)-2)]
[[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 10], [4, 10, 20], [10, 20, 30], [20, 30, 102]]
```