# what is the best algorithm to get repetition of k length substring in a string in the shortest possible time?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, sequence, dynamic-programming

Is there any algorithm to get number of repeating overlap substrings in an string? This question is similar to [Splitting a Python list into a list of overlapping chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586897/splitting-a-python-list-into-a-list-of-overlapping-chunks), but in my case changed elements are first and last elements of each substring! 
for example when:

```
string = "HelloWorld"
k = 4
```

then:

```
subString = ["Hell","ello","lloW","loWo","oWor","Worl","orld"]
```

i tried this:

```
i = 0
while len(string[i+4:])>=4:
    i+=1
print i
```

Comment: `substr = [ string[i:i+2] for i in range(len(string)-1)]` ?

Comment: Show what have you tried.

Comment: and unless you throw in a `lower()` it wont change the capital `H` to lower `h` ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner you should post that answer, I don't think there is a dupe for that one in particular as it's prettry general with the k-length substring, moreover: overlapping.

Comment: @Patrick Artner so true you are.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Oh you are right, I didn't look for answers with lists

Comment: @PatrickArtner Threre is not dupe, in my case, all elements of the each previous sub-list except first element include as elements in the next sub-list.

Comment: @Monako See my answer then

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Oh, Yes, you are right.

Comment: It is a dupe - if you need more then 2 characters (which was the OP before you edited) then you simply have to change the amount of characters you take in the sublist. I do not really think that we need 10 answers for sublists of 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 things. If you wanted 4 chracters you would use `substr = [ string[i:i+4] for i in range(len(string)-3)]` - the -3 making sure you only get length 4 sublists. @OlivierMelançon kindly wrote an answer, you could accept his as it does what you wanted. For other answers look into the answers of the dupe. Being a dupe does not mean your OP is bad.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can return all *k*-length slices of the strings with a list-comprehension.

```
def substrings(s, k=2):
    return [s[i:i+k] for i in range(len(s) - k + 1)]

s = "Hello"

print(substrings(s, k=2)) # ['He', 'el', 'll', 'lo']
print(substrings(s, k=3)) # ['Hel', 'ell', 'llo']
```