# Slicing a list with variable chunk size in Python

Tags: python, list

I worked in Python 3.6, and I am a beginner. So can anyone give me a true way of how can slice a list into variable size sub-list. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231663/slicing-a-list-into-a-list-of-sub-lists) solution from this site, but it gave me fixed size of sliced list. To clarify:

if I have this list:

```
inputList= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I want the output to be like e.g.:

```
outputList=[[0,1,2], [3,4], [5], [6,7]]
```

each time it depends on (for example) user input or some variable size.

Comment: How do you decide the slices? Your example doesn't offer us much to help you with.

Comment: for example in my own project I want to slice the list of number based on count of word occurrences in a text comes after a word. so this is not matter actually because I need the idea. i.e. let word occurrences = n, so whatever n is equal to? the list should slice in a sub-list based on n with its variable size each time as I mentioned above. i hope that is clear I don't no how can i explain it to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). This has the added advantage that if you request a slice that you would normally take you out of bounds, you won't get an error. You'll just get as many items are left as possible.

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> input_list = range(8)
>>> slices = (3, 2, 1, 2)
>>> iterable = iter(input_list)
>>> output_list = [list(it.islice(iterable, sl)) for sl in slices]
>>> output_list
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [6, 7]]
```

For example, if you had `slices = (3, 2, 1, 3, 2)`, your result would be `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [6, 7], []]`.

Basically, `iter(input_list)` creates an iterable of your list so you can fetch the next `k` values with `islice()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a loop making use of python's `[:#]` slice notation:

Let's say the user's input for slicing chunk sizes is stored in a list. They want chunks of 3, 2, 1 and 2, so the user input defining the chunks gets stored into a list that has has `[3,2,1,2]`.

Then, loop through that list and use it to get your slices:

```
input_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
chunk_list = [3,2,1,2]
output_list = []
for i in chunk_list:
    output_list.append(input_list[:i])
    input_list = input_list[i:]
print(output_list)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: By the way, if anyone has a better way to say "python's `[:#]` slicing format", please do share. I realized how silly that looks, but I can't think of a better name.

Comment: "Slice notation"

Comment: That sounds way better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just want to learn about slicing. See [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

To get your example output, you could do

```
outputList = [inputList[:3], inputList[3:5], inputList[5:6], inputList[6:]]
```